# FFMPEG-Unrecognized option 'hls_key_info_file'

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, http-live-streaming

I use ffmpeg to convert file .mp4 into file hls(.m3u8). But i meet problem when i want add key to file. I run command in the directory. Folder include:

- File video have name : namhh_123.mp4
- File "file.keyinfo":

  file.key 
  ./file.key
  9e1c83a7e2d04fe930cce5c8ef5c5bd0
- File file.key

After that i run command:  `ffmpeg -i 123_namhh.mp4 -hls_time 10 -hls_key_info_file file.keyinfo out.m3u8`

Unrecognized option 'hls_key_info_file'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

*My ffmpeg's version:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
```

My OS : CentOS 7

Please help me how to solve this problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to already compiled `ffmpeg` builds for Linux, macOS, or Windows. Or follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

For Linux, if you downloaded or compiled, and you want the new `ffmpeg` binary to be in your `PATH` (to make it the default "`ffmpeg`"), you can place it in `/usr/local/bin`. Alternatively, for Debian/Ubuntu & CentOS, you can place it in `~/bin`, then log out/in or run `source ~/.profile`. Now when you run the `ffmpeg` command it should use the new version.

Comment: I installed new ffmpeg follow your complie guide. Now i have 2 version ffmpeg. Please help me how to make new version of ffmpeg is default. My new version locate at Home/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg. I run command which ffmpeg ... show old version located at /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: thanks for your answer,  i have solved problem and everything work well

Comment: @HoangNam Good to hear you figured it out. I added a paragraph to the answer clarifying how to make the new version the default.